# Apache Phoenix on HBase-subquery giving error "org.apache.phoenix.parse.InParseNode"

Tags: apache-phoenix

I have a table named as EVENTLOG where I have 3 columns: (CASEID VARCHAR(200), DATEPLUSTIME TIMESTAMP, SUBSTATUS VARCHAR(200))

```
SELECT SUBSTATUS 
  FROM EVENTLOG 
 WHERE DATEPLUSTIME IN
       (SELECT MIN(DATEPLUSTIME) 
          FROM EVENTLOG 
         GROUP BY CASEID);
```

When I am performing the above query in SQuirrel SQL CLIENT and ./sqlline.py script, I got the below error in SQuirreL SQL CLient

```
Error:   org.apache.phoenix.parse.InParseNode[CASEID,org.apache.phoenix.parse.SubqueryParseNode@6580cf aa]
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 0
```

and got different error for same query in ./sqlline.py as described below

```
Error: org.apache.phoenix.parse.InParseNode[DATEPLUSTIME, org.apache.phoenix.parse.SubqueryParseNode@4017415d] (state=,code=0)
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You might try: `SELECT E1.SubStatus FROM EventLog AS E1 WHERE E1.DatePlusTime IN (SELECT MIN(E2.DatePlusTime) FROM EventLog AS E2 GROUP BY E2.CaseID)`.  If this works, then the parser is confused (buggy), presumably because the subquery uses the same table as the main part of the query.  However, the revised query has no right to work where the original does not; they should be equivalent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I tried with your Query but still i am getting the same error, i am using version 4.0 of PHOENIX

Comment: I'd not heard of Apache Phoenix or SQuirrel SQL Client before I edited your question; I have nothing more to offer, therefore, except the observation that the original SQL you entered should be OK, so I've no idea what's going wrong or where it is going wrong. In debugging, maybe you should run the sub-query on its own, and check whether that works, and what its results are. And, assuming you get some results from that, you could then create a variant of the main query, listing some or all of those values explicitly in the IN clause, and see whether that works.  Both should be fine, of course.

Comment: The version of Phoenix you're using does probably not support subqueries. Version 4.0 does not seem to support them.

Comment: @Kunal this error will come if your inner query is returning null. I have also faced the same issue earlier. Just check the result for your inner query.